# useState doesn't update its value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, gatsby

I'm creating a input form for an e-mail and i have a delayed onChange on it to not call the api too many times.

Here's my code:

```
const InformationCollection = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState()
  const [collectedEmail, setCollectedEmail] = useState(1)

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setCollectedEmail(email)
      console.log(collectedEmail)
    }, 500)
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
    }
  }, [email])

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="inputmail">Email address</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setEmail(e.target.value)
              console.log(e.target.value + "this is what is set" + email)
            }}
            aria-label="Enter e-mail address"
          />
        </div>
    )
}

export default InformationCollection
```

On this line if i type "1" `console.log(e.target.value + "this is what is set" + email)`, e.target.value is 1, but `email` is undefined.

On the next character "12", e.target.value is 12 but `email` is 1

Can anyone help with this?

UPDATE:

The solution is to have 2 useEffectHooks. One for the value in the form `email` and one for the delayed value `collectedEmail`

Second solution is to do fetch inside the first useEffect hook

```
const InformationCollection = (props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState()
  const [collectedEmail, setCollectedEmail] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      //fetch directly here
      setCollectedEmail(email)
      console.log(collectedEmail)
    }, 500)
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
    }
  }, [email])

  useEffect(() => {
    //fetch() here
    console.log(collectedEmail) //right value
  }, [collectedEmail])

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="inputmail">Email address</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setEmail(e.target.value)
              console.log(e.target.value + "this is what is set" + email)
            }}
            aria-label="Enter e-mail address"
          />
        </div>
    )
}

export default InformationCollection
```

Comment: My guess is that setstate has not finished before you call console.log. If you were to console.log inside the useEffect loop I suspect you would get the values you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

state is updated asynchronously, that's why `email` is undefined for the first time when you try to log it after updating the state.

You can log the email inside `useEffect` hook which will be called after email has changed.

> On the next character "12", e.target.value is 12 but email is 1

`email` is `1` because when `onChange` event fired for the first time, `email` was undefined but when `onChange` event fires for the second time, `email` had already been updated asynchronously to `1`

Comment: I see what you mean. I already have that useEffect hook on [email]. My question is, when i do run my fetch()? I want my fetch to be on collectedEmail (because its the one that only updates rarely). Do i do a second useEffect hook for collectedEmail?

Comment: You can use `fetch` inside the `setTimeout` function. You don't need a second `useEffect` hook

Comment: @Link see [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8m9hd2) which fetches todos from jsonplaceholder api. input value is saved in one state and the fetched todo is saved in another. You will see that only that todo is fetched whose id  is same as the one user entered and it only uses one `useEffect` hook

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this expected behaviour?  `email` is always the value before the change inside the `onChange` handler.  Because the re-render hasn't happened yet.

To see the value rendered do this:

```
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="inputmail">Email address: { email }</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setEmail(e.target.value)
              console.log(e.target.value + "this is what is set" + email)
            }}
            aria-label="Enter e-mail address"
          />
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Okay, so i see that the value is right when i do that. But where do i do my fetch() ? Inside setTimeout, the value is still 1 character behind

Comment: I guess the solution is to have a second useEffect hook on collectedEmail

Comment: @Link _Inside setTimeout, the value is still 1 character behind_ no it won't be 1 character behind because `useEffect` hook will run when `email` changes and before it runs, it will clear the previous `setTimeout` and will set a new timeout with the updated value of  `email`